# Understanding hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

An exercise says:

> Create three hashes called person1, person2, and person3, with first
>   and last names under the keys `:first` and `:last`. Then create a params
>   hash so that `params[:father]` is person1, `params[:mother]` is person2,
>   and `params[:child]` is person3. Verify that, for example,
>   `params[:father][:first]` has the right value.

I did

```
person1 = {first: "Thom", last: "Bekker"}
person2 = {first: "Kathy", last: "Bekker"}
person2 = {first: "Anessa", last: "Bekker"}
```

then the `params` hash in Rails

```
params = {}
params[:father] = person1
params[:mother] = person2
params[:child] = person3
```

Now I can ask for father, mother or child's first or last name like so
`params[:father][:first]` gives me `"Thom"`.

What makes `params[:father][:first][:last]` return an error? Is there a way to make that return `"Thom Bekker"`?

I have no way to check if the way I came up with is correct, is there a better way to do the exercise?

Is there a reason why `symbol:` is better than `symbol =>`?

Comment: Community nitpick, try to stick to one question per post or number your questions so that I can be sure to answer them all. :)

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Yes, the restriction of asking just one question is strictly enforced at SO. However, you can post a separate question, "Is there a reason why `symbol:` is better than `symbol =>`?", in which case most responders would probably say the choice is only a matter of personal preference, though someone may argue that the former is preferred at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: FYI: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` is caused by trying to index into `params[:father][:first]` using `:last`. Using an Integer still won't do what you want, but at least it won't raise an exception. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Return Value is a Single Hash Object

You're misunderstanding the type of object you're getting back. `params[:father]` returns a single [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html) object, not an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) or an Array of hashes. For example:

```
params[:father]
#=> {:first=>"Thom", :last=>"Bekker"}

params[:father].class
#=> Hash
```

So, you can't access the missing third element (e.g. `:last`) because there's no such element within the value of `params[:father][:first]`.

Instead, you could deconstruct the Hash:

```
first, last = params[:father].values
#=> ["Thom", "Bekker"]
```

or do something more esoteric like:

```
p params[:father].values.join " "
#=> "Thom Bekker"
```

The point is that you have to access the *values* of the Hash, or convert it to an Array first, rather than treating it directly like an Array and trying to index into multiple values at once.

Comment: Hello, Gnome. I see you're back from one of your world tours. This may be nit-picking, but since the OP is a newbie, I think it's important that the language be precise: the method [Hash#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) in invoked on the `Hash` instance `params`, returning a `Hash` object (e.g., `person1`). The OP should understand that it's the method `[]` that returns the object, where the object returned is the value of  `params[:father]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Both Hash and Array both have a #[] method; params is only a Hash because the OP created it as a Hash with a literal (e.g. `{}`). The point is that for the OP, `params[:father].class == Hash`. In Ruby, every expression returns a value; in this case, the value of of `params[:father]` is a Hash object, which is the real source of the OP's (admittedly obscure) TypeError exception when attempting to index via a Symbol. His real question is about how to access the data; the rest is a side-trip at best.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I just wanted to point out to the OP (the nit-pik) that where you say `params[:father]` returns a single `Hash` object" it's not ``params[:father]` that returns the object; that holds the value that is returned by the method `[]`.`.I would not have mentioned it had the OP not been a newbie, as it's quite clear to most all readers what you mean.  (But maybe I've just confused the OP.) btw, I see you recently spent some time in the [Bay Area](http://evenkeelpodiatry.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gnome2.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, using square brackets on the [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html) or other classes is actually using a method available for an object of that class ([this one](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)). When you call these methods in your example, each of these methods will be called and will return its result before the next method is called. So, as you've defined it:

> 1. Calling `[:father]` on `params` returns the hash represented by `person1`
> 2. `[:first]` is then called on `{first: "Thom", last: "Bekker"}`, returning the corresponding value in the hash, `"Thom"`
> 3. `[:last]` is called on `"Thom"`, which results in an error. Calling square brackets on a string with an integer between them can access the character in a string at that index (`person1[:first][0]` returns `"T"`), but `"Thom"` doesn't have a way of handling the `:last` symbol inside the square brackets.

There are a number of ways you could get the names printed as you wanted, one of the simplest being combining the string values in `person1`:

`params[:father][:first] + " " + params[:father][:last]`
returns `"Thom Bekker"`

Comment: There's nothing "behind the scenes" about" [Hash#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D). It's just a garden-variety method that looks a bit odd. Ke0: think of it as `{:a => 1}.value_for_key(:a) # => 1`. Also, it's invoked on a `Hash` object, not the `Hash` class, and like many methods, takes an argument, which here is a hash key.

Comment: You're right, I've corrected the vague language above.

Answer (score 0):

> So here's my question, what exactly makes params[:father][:first][:last] return an error? Is there a way to make that return "Thom Bekker"?

Both of these would work

1. `params[:father][:first] + params[:father][:last]`
2. `params[:father].values.join(' ')`

But maybe it would be better to think about them like the nested structures that they are:

```
father = params[:father]
name   = father[:first] + father[:last]
puts name
```

To answer your last question, pretend that there's no difference between a hashrocket `=>` and `symbol:`. This is one where you don't need to care for a long time. Maybe around year 2 start asking this again, but for learning treat them as if they were equivalent.

(Full disclosure, there are differences, but this is a holy war that you really don't want to see played out)